# ggplot annotation_custom image not plotting in correct y-axis

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, png

I've made a scatter plot with dates on the x-axis and continuous score on the y-axis.

On certain dates, I'd like to plot an image of the moon over those dates, however the image doesn't seem to plot on the y-axis correctly.

I'm plotting a png that is 296 pixel wide and high, and trying to use the x/y min and max parameters to set the height.

Edit - here is the image
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


rm(list = ls())

startDate <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2017-01-01")

testData <- data.frame(dater = seq(startDate, endDate, by = "day"),
                       score = rnorm(367, 50, 10)
)


imgP <- filter(testData, dater %in% as.Date(c("2016-04-01")))

gTest <- ggplot(testData, aes(x=dater, y=score)) +
            geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(20, 70, 5))


img1 <- readPNG("G:/MHOShare/MHO Staff/James Holland/TempDump/themoon.png")
g1 <- rasterGrob(img1, interpolate=TRUE)

gTest + annotation_custom(g1, xmin = imgP$dater,
                          xmax = imgP$dater + 10,
                          ymin = 50,
                          ymax = 55)
```

This produces this image, but no corner of the image seems to be at 50 or 55.  It seems to be showing the image in between those two values.  I think that's because the grob is expected to fill that whole area, so it centers it; but the png should be much wider than that space.

Do I need to use a smaller image?

[image]

Comment: Could you share  `themoon.png` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly on my R 3.4.2. This is the result I get using a different `themoon.png` image:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(png)
library(grid)
library(RCurl)

startDate <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
testData <- data.frame(dater = seq(startDate, endDate, by = "day"),
                       score = rnorm(367, 50, 10)
)

imgP <- filter(testData, dater %in% as.Date(c("2016-04-01")))
gTest <- ggplot(testData, aes(x=dater, y=score)) +
            geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(20, 70, 5))

img1 <- readPNG(getURLContent("http://www.dunakin.com/projects/solarsystem/images/TheMoon.png"))
g1 <- rasterGrob(img1, interpolate=TRUE)

gTest + annotation_custom(g1, xmin = imgP$dater, xmax = imgP$dater + 10, ymin = 50, ymax = 55)
```

[image]